# How to Integrate the index page designed in Wordpress to the existing asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

Client gave a new design for index page Which created in wordpress.I want to convert the page (only design) into my asp.net project.Its contains some animations etc.HOw its possible..Is there any converter software or any other ways to do that?

Comment: Animations are made in css ?

Comment: language doesn't matters after all in browser it will be served as pure `html` you just need to use that in your asp.net

Comment: Is there any <?php get_header(); ?> line in your index.php file??

Comment: Great...tell them to give you all files and folders where index.php staying. This is the folder of theme in wordpress. All themes are located in wordpress is "website root folder/wp-content/themes/themename"...after this I will let you know how to design page in asp.net.